# Magento API malfunctioning with a specific (rack-space)hosting

Tags: api, magento, soap-client

I am working on Magento Soap API v2 and developing a desktop C# application.

Correct behaviour :

1. On another hosting this magento api works fine anyway
2. On this hosting (rack-space), If I open the api link (http://162.242.xx.xx/dnmagento/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1) through browser, it works fine

**Undesired behaviour:** On this hosting (rack-space), I can not connect api programatically (c# or php)

```
  private void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      magWebReference.MagentoService mag = new magWebReference.MagentoService();

      // Throws exception here
      string sessionID=mag.login("apiuser","password"); 

      MessageBox.Show(sessionID);
  }
```

I get following error while connecting

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://162.242.xx.xx/dnmagento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity "http://162.242.xxx.xx/dnmagento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1"

**Note :** In reported error **/index/ is automatically added** after /v2_soap. while in provided link there is no /index/.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a problem when the PHP soap client itself cannot resolve the URL for the SOAP client. I had faced a similar issue previously and found the issue to be in the server setup. The magento server setup maybe rejecting any calls which does not have a user agent string attached to it. Please do a check on the HTTP access logs and confirm if this is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem upgrading to Magento 1.9.0.1. I solved the problem with [this official patch](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce19-later-release-notes#ce19-patches-soap)